# Saving rotation Matrix in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm writing an OpenGl program about a cone rotating in 3D space and I have a txt with datas of the angles and the axes  around whom the rotation takes place.
The problem is that OpenGL requires the total rotation angle while in the file I have the increment in angle for every time step.

here my code :

```
GLdouble matrice1 []  {1.,0,0,0,0,1.,0,0,0,0,1.,0,0,0,0,1.};
GLdouble * matrice = matrice1;


void displayCone(void){

    // clear the drawing buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  //

    // set matrix mode
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // clear model view matrix
    glLoadIdentity();
    

    //gluLookAt(3.0, 3.0, 3.0-4.5, 0.0, 0.0,-4.5,0,0,1);
    gluLookAt(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0,0,1);




    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 2.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);
    glEnd();

 

    
    //glLoadMatrixd(matrice);

    glColor3f(0.8, 0.2, 0.1);

glMultMatrixd(matrice);  // <------ ** me trying to implement the previous rotation before //rotating of the increment angle xRotated 
    glRotated(xRotated,a1,a2,a3);    // <----- **here the rotation**
      
      glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW, matrice); // <----- ** me trying to save the total rotation //matrix ** 

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, height);
    glutSolidCone(base,height,slices,stacks);
glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, height-0.1);
    glutSolidCylinder(0.07,height_c,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(1.0,1.0,-1.0);
//glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 2*height);

//glPopMatrix();



//glPushMatrix();
  glutSolidCone(base,height,slices,stacks);

    // Flush buffers to screen
glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();


}
```

What I'm trying to do here with `glGetDoublev`and `glMultMatrixd`is to save the precedent Rotation Angle but this doesn't work. Does anyone know how to save the precedent rotation matrix in order to get the total rotation and not the RotationAngle of the increment angle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, that code you have there is using the old and busted fixed function, legacy API that's been out of fashion for well over 15 years.

More to the point, you can use a proper 3D graphics math library (GLM, Eigen, linmath.h) to manage a rotation matrix and apply it to the OpenGL transformation matrix stack using `glMultMatrix` instead of using multiple calls to `glRotate`. Or manage the whole transformation matrix yourself and just load it with `glLoadMatrix`.

And when you do your own matrix management, it's only a small step to ditch the fixed function pipeline and use shaders, where you pass the matrix as so called *uniform* values.

Comment: I tried before with glLoadMatrixd (using then glGetDoublev first initialised with identity) instead of glMultMatrix but the result is the same . Would you please write a snippet in which you show me where to put the functions you told me? I am not very good in OpenGL yet @datenwolf

Comment: in particoular where would you write glLoadMatrix in my code? And how much is better to use GLM ?

Comment: @Jatos: Right before drawing things. If you really, really want to stick to the old, legacy, fixed function pipeline, you'd have something like 'glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadMatrix(my_projection_matrix); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadMatrix(my_modelview_matrix); glDraw…(…);` – But why would you want to stick with the old, legacy stuff anyway? Unless you're raiding my basement you'll be hard pressed to find any machine in the wild that doesn't use shaders internally, and if you're using the fixed function pipeline what you do with it must be translated into equivalent shaders.